# Is it possible to test (or access) custom methods defined in a react component in react shallow render?

Tags: reactjs

React recommends shallow rendering for testing but is there a way i can test custom methods defined in a component. I can do it by renderingIntoDocument. But want to know if its possible through shallow rendering.